# Assistance with a simple WSO2 ESB project

Tags: esb, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm very very new to this and need some help writing an ESB script to take an event posted via HTTPS on Port 9090 in WSO2 and transform it into a message to be apended to an XML file on the server:

The HTTPS data will contain : “ID=Servername|Severity=sevtype” (Where Servername is a device name and Sevtype can either be "WARNING" or "OK" depending on whether the server is down or up)

This then needs to be transformed and appended to an existing XML file in the following format:

```
<event>
<componentID>Servername</componentID>
<timestamp>2012-04-27 01:37:10</timestamp> ***(Date and time the event was received)***
<severity>NORMAL</severity>    ***(If original is WARNING then severity = SEVERE else it = NORMAL)***
<eti>NodeStatus</eti><etivalue>Up</etivalue> ***(If original is WARNING then severity = Down else it = Up)***

<\event>
```

Please could someone assist me i'm really floundering with what seems to be a simple thing

Many Many Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple task to poll your data into the server and can do a xslt transformation to construct that particular xml format message.

Some references to write a task;

http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/configuration_language.html#TaskConcept

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB403/Writing+Tasks

http://wso2.org/library/2900

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the ID and Severity? are they http headers?

Generally you can use payload factory mediator[1] to build the payload messages with some input parameter data.

[1] http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/message_mediation_samples.html#Sample17

Comment: Hi Amila, Thanks for your reply, the ID and Severity are sent from a service mgt tool (eg Tivoli) using a curl command to port 9090 on WSO2 and are in the HTTPS headers